# Read the penultimate value ssrs

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

i have a report with parameter is the year i can select a multiple value

```
            year
Data        2010    2011   2012
 hp          14      25     30
 Dell        17      18     20
```

what i need when i create the report i want to have another column with the last value concatenation with the last previous one like this :

```
           year
Data        2010    2011   2012  2012/2011
 hp          14      25     30    3025
 Dell        17      18     20    2018
```

i tried this :

```
=Last(Field!Qte.value)+Last(Field!Qte.value)-1
```

but i had the wrong result i got this result :

```
 year
Data        2010    2011   2012  2012/2011
 hp          14      25     30    3029
 Dell        17      18     20    2019
```

the problem is in this function

```
Last(Field!Qte.value)-1
```

it doesn't return the last previous value

Comment: Unfortunately there is no penultimate() function, and you cannot do Last(Last(field.value)). There are some work arounds. Are your last two years always consecutive? Or could they be something like 2012/2010?

Comment: i need the two last years for example i selected 2010 2011 2012 2013 i need the value of 2013 and 2012 because i need to do some calculation